# Does "I am well, thank you. And you?" expect an answer?

Tags: responses

Suppose that somebody greets you, and asks "How are you?" You answer with "I am well, thank you. And you?" Should an answer be expected?

I know that who answers could say "I am well too." even if it is not true, but would not answering be understood negatively?

If it would happen to me, and I don't hear any answer to my "I am well, thank you. And you?" I would think I have not spoken loudly enough to be understood, and I would probably repeat what I said.

Comment: This has practically nothing to do with language *qua* language, and almost everything to do with social ritual. At some point the phatic stroking has to end, and different folks will end it at different points; so repeating what you said would be a mildly hostile rejection of your interlocutor's decision to terminate.

Comment: Actually, it was me who first asked "How are you?" and who should have answered to "And you?" The second paragraph just says that if I would have said "I am well, thank you. And you?" without getting an answer, I would have thought my English was not that good, or who greeted me didn't hear what I said. I don't get your other part; do you meant that I could avoid answering to who asks me "How are you?" Is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect an answer, although I wouldn't expect more than a polite "Fine, thanks" or similar.

I think most English speakers would answer with something, but the question is usually out of politeness and a full answer isn't usually expected. Unless you're particularly close, they probably wouldn't give a long-winded explanation, in the same way you first answered “I am well, thank you. And you?”

If they don't answer, I wouldn't really worry about it as it's usually a courtesy to the other person, and I'd just continue the conversation as normal.

---

An exception: My mum once told me she went to visit the doctor. He asked: "Hello, how are you?" She answered: "Fine, thanks." Then after a moment realised it wasn't just a polite question and said: "Oh, are you really asking? Well, I... [the reason for visiting the doctor]".

Comment: If an Italian doctor would ask "How are you?" I would take it as a polite question, for which I would give a polite answer. If the doctor would want to know why I took an appointment, he should ask me "What takes you here?" or something similar.